# SQL code runs manually but not in job

Tags: sql-server

I am using this code in a automated job , job got failed once it comes on this code but if I run this manually it works perfect.  Is there any  other way to write this or is there any error.

```
UPDATE ABC_FACT
SET ID =  CASE WHEN (PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%ETH LE%' or PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '% SOUND %' OR PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%NET REV%' or PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%ETHERNET SPOKE%')
THEN ORDER_NO + (SUBSTRING(ORDER,1,CHARINDEX('/',ORDER)-1)) + C_TYPE
ELSE ORDER_NO + ORDER + C_TYPE END
WHERE FLAG LIKE 'ABC%'
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Is this job scheduled on sql server. There must be error message somewhere from where you execute it.

Comment: Without an error, it's hard to guess. but if I had to, I would guess the account the job is executing under doesn't have permission to update the table.

Comment: I am surprised this works when you run it manually, you appear to have a column called `ORDER`, which, being a reserved word, will cause a compilation error unless you refer to it as `[ORDER]` (or `"ORDER"`)

Comment: There is some error in this -
 (SUBSTRING(ORDER,1,CHARINDEX('/',ORDER)-1))

Comment: One of your records in `ORDER` satisfies the criteria of your `CASE` predicate, but does not contain the character `/`, this means that when you call `CHARINDEX('/',ORDER)`, the value returned is 0, meaning you then pass a length of -1 to the substring function here: `SUBSTRING(ORDER,1,CHARINDEX('/',ORDER)-1))`. I don't know what your desired outcome would be in this scenario, so I can't suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UPDATE ABC_FACT
SET ID =  CASE WHEN (PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%ETH LE%' or PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '% SOUND %' OR PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%NET REV%' or PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%ETHERNET SPOKE%')
THEN ORDER_NO + (SUBSTRING([ORDER],1,CHARINDEX('/',[ORDER])-1)) + C_TYPE
ELSE ORDER_NO + [ORDER] + C_TYPE END
WHERE FLAG LIKE 'ABC%'
```

Order is reserved word in SQL, whenever use reserved word as a column use [], but I recommend don't use reserved words as columns name, you can use it like _ before or with other combination of words

for list of SQL Server Reserved Words please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql

Comment: I am sorry. I am using the same. Error Msg is -  Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: can you post table structure and sample data so i can check it

Comment: Data Structure  - [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ff4b7/2) , Complete error is  Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 537)  The statement has been terminated. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  The step failed.